# Arduino UPS without reset

Tags: arduino-uno, power, battery

I’m trying to figure out how to make arduino UPS (when the power goes down it should not reset the arduino). Or preferably buy something that will do that for me. I found [this](https://www.laskarduino.cz/wemos-d1-mini-lithium-battery-shield/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0JK047rR8gIVUeJ3Ch0GnASEEAQYAiABEgIIV_D_BwE), but Im not sure of it will work. I will normally be using power from the outlet, but in case of power outage, I want it to run on the 3,7V li-pol battery (best would be if arduino could somehow know that its running on battery) What solution would you recommend to me?

Comment: There are charger modules, which provide power passthrough. I'm not sure if they can provide uninterrupted power during switching, but a large capacitor may help with that depending on the needed current

Comment: @chrisl and could the arduino somehow know if its running on battery or from the outlet?

Comment: @chrisl well i guess i could just power up radio transciever “directly” from the outlet

Comment: That unit does not properly charge a li-pol battery and it states that. It appears it probably would work for Ni-Cad or Pb-Acid batteries. My recommendation is get a unit designed for the batteries you are using with power pass through. Also how do you regulate it for your arduino, a boost module of some type? Showing a schematic, not a frizzy thing would help a lot.